# Crystal Report Login: "The report you requested requires further information."

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, crystal-reports, report

Every time I run my program, it prompts me to input the username and password however it keeps me on the same page even though I placed the correct username and password. So, I searched and placed the code that can be seen below on the PageLoad method of my form and still the problem occurs and couldn't be solve. Is there alternative solution for this? By the way, I am using VS2008 and my database is Oracle 11g.

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ADMIN/AdminReport.rpt"));

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "localhost";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "";
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "******;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "******";
        crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

thanks in advance, 
Ernie

Comment: I don't know much about Oracle, but doesn't IntegratedSecurity should be false if you supply user & password?

Comment: Does the report have parameters? `RefreshReport()` would require them....

Comment: I use the wizard in creating my crystal report (I think I didn't use any parameter) then I tried using this from the other website used it as my solution because of the problem when logging in. However, no luck for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for postback on pageload.  You are resetting the report on every postback which is why you stay on page 1.  Add this to you pageload method:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. however, i don't know what should i put inside the if(!IsPostback)

Comment: The code you posted in your question.  Hence "Your code here".